# Spring Controller testing when url is protected to on ADMIN user

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I am just getting into TDD and trying to add a test that will test a controller for saving an entity.

//Controller method to save a new entity

```
@PostMapping("/management/member/{societyId:[0-9]+}")
    GenericResponse create(@Valid @RequestBody Member member, @PathVariable long societyId) {
        memberService.save(member, societyId);

        return new GenericResponse("member saved");
    }
```

//Security config file

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();

        http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));

        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "SUPERADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

all url's behind `/management` are protected and only accessible by someone with `ADMIN` role.

So far in my `controllerTest`,

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MemberControllerTest {

    private static final String USERS = "/member";

    @Autowired
    TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @Autowired
    MemberRepo memberRepo;

    @Autowired
    MemberService memberService;

    @Autowired
    SocietyService societyService;

    @Autowired
    AppConfiguration appConfiguration;

    @BeforeEach
    public void cleanup() {
        memberRepo.deleteAll();
        testRestTemplate.getRestTemplate().getInterceptors().clear();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void before() {
        // because .withBasicAuth() creates a new TestRestTemplate with the same
        // configuration as the autowired one.
        testRestTemplate = testRestTemplate.withBasicAuth("username", "password");
    }

    @Test
    public void postUser_whenUserIsValid_receiveOk() {
        Society s = TestUtil.createValidSociety();
        String url = "/management/" + USERS + "/1";
        testRestTemplate.postForEntity(url, s, Object.class);
        Member member = TestUtil.createValidMember();
        ResponseEntity<Object> response = testRestTemplate.withBasicAuth("dannyjebb", 
           "P4ssword1234")
                .postForEntity("/management/member/1", member, Object.class);
        //ResponseEntity<Object> response = postSignup(member, Object.class);
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

     public <T> ResponseEntity<T> postSignup(Object request, Class<T> response) {
        return testRestTemplate.postForEntity(USERS, request, response);
    }
```

I am using the `withBasicAuth` but not sure how I tell it that the authenticated user is `ADMIN`?

The controller works fine when I test the controller with postman and can only be called if the basic authentication is someone with an ADMIN or SUPERADMIN role.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you configure spring security to load the user for authentication . For example ,if you are using the default JDBC authentication , you can use `@MockBean` to replace default `UserDetailsService` with a mocked one and stub its `loadUserByUsername()` to return an user with ADMIN role.

But if you just want to test if the rest controller is configured correctly and return the expected HTTP response given a HTTP request , you can simply use `MockMvc` rather than `TestRestTemplate` . The nice things about `MockMvc` is that it allows you to use `@WithMockUser` to configure the role for the user directly and it also run fasters since it does not need to start the server .

Also you should consider to use `@WebMvcTest` rather than `@SpringBootTest` as `@WebMvcTest` will only enable the beans related to web layers but `@SpringBootTest` will enable all beans by default such as starting an embeddable DB etc. which is not necessary for testing the controller.

And also use `@MockBean` to  replace all the dependencies of the controller such that you can stub their response and also verify if your controller interact with them correctly.

It should look something like:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(MemberController.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MemberControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    MemberRepo memberRepo;


    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = "ADMIN")
    public void postUser_whenUserIsValid_receiveOk() {
        Member member = TestUtil.createValidMember();

        //stub the memberRepo if necessary

        mockMvc.perform(post("/management/" + USERS + "/1")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content(memberJsonStr)
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
  
    }
 }
```